Is Sky Vegas website free spin money haram or halal?
One of my friends has Sky vegas account. They give free spin every day. One day he got some money on free spin where he had nothing to lose.He didn’t paid any money. He just spin everyday like time passing & to see if it’s true that people actually get money on free spin.
Now is that money haram.Can he use that money?
